# Scala define mapper of superclass

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm trying to create a mapper of the superclass instance and pass it to a collection of the parent type:

```
def numberToString =  (n:Number) => n.toString()
List(1.1, 2.1, 3.1).map(numberToString)
```

Error:

```
type mismatch; found : Number => String required: Double => ?
```

I'm surprised that the map method in Scala doesn't allow functions of a super type. Is there a better way how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no type `Number` in Scala, so I am guessing you are meaning `Numeric` (`Double` is not a sub-class of `Numeric`, but it can be coerced to `Numeric` via implicit conversion).

If so, you can achieve what you want by specifying `Numeric` as a context bound for the parameter of the `numberToString` function (ie. specify that there must be an in-scope implicit conversion from the argument type to `Numeric`, which will generally be true for `Int`, `Double`, etc):

```
scala> def numberToString[N : Numeric] =  (n: N) => n.toString()
numberToString: [N](implicit evidence$1: Numeric[N])N => String

scala> List(1.1, 2.1, 3.1).map(numberToString2)
res2: List[String] = List(1.1, 2.1, 3.1)
```

**EDIT**

Note that I am assuming here that you want to stay as much as possible in the Scala world. If you do intend restricting the argument to `numberToString` to the `java.lang.Number` type rather than `scala.math.Numeric`, then use the similar view bounds notation as given by @wingedsubmariner.

Comment: Oh, it didn't realize that there is no connection between Java's Number and Scala's double type. If I correct my code to `List(new Double(1.1), new Double(2.1), new Double(3.1)).map(numberToString)` it does exactly what I want, and it looks like Scala's generics are not so strict as in Java, it's what I was trying to prove. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Scala does allow you to pass a function that accepts a super type to `map`. This actually works by upcasting the sequence, not by accepting the function as is:

```
def intSeqToInt(x: Seq[Int]) = x.length
List(List(1), List(2)).map(intSeqToInt)
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 1)
```

List[List[Int]] is cast to List[Seq[Int]], and then its `map` has the proper type for `intSeqToInt`.

Your problem is that Double is not a subclass of Number. Number refers to java.lang.Number, Double is scala.Double, which is only a subclass of AnyVal. There is an implicit conversion from Double to Number, but in this instance you have to specifically ask for it with a view bound:

```
def numberToString[N <% Number](n:N) = n.toString()
List(1.1, 2.1, 3.1).map(numberToString[Double])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a super type is allowed, except that... `Number` is `java.lang.Number`, which is not a super type of `scala.Double`.

An example with an actual super type:

```
scala> def numberToString =  (n:AnyVal) => n.toString()
numberToString: AnyVal => String

scala> List(1.1, 2.1, 3.1).map(numberToString)
res0: List[String] = List(1.1, 2.1, 3.1)
```

Obviously you could just use `_.toString` here, but I suppose this is just a simplified version of your problem.

*Edit*: in the special case of numeric values, the proper way would be to use `Numeric` as in @Shadowlands's answer.